# how can I make a border around the whole page using TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Just as the title asks. I've been struggling with using TCPDF for reports for the website i work on and my boss wants some of them to have a table stretching all the way down to the bottom of the page. I just can't get any bordered container to stretch all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the [mothod Line](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a89c0fac95da962719ba92b057df9c201)

Use one line for each side of the page by setting the right size.